# How to set class weights by dictionary for imbalanced classes in Keras or Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How may I create a dictionary in Keras or Tensorflow with the `class_weights` parameter?

I have a dataset with 12 classes. I split them with 70% of Train and 15% of test and validation. However, my training set classes are imbalanced. The classes contain the image data as below:

class 1 to 12: 217, 317, 235, 489, 177, 377, 534, 180, 425,192, 403, 324

Images respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the class weight dictionary determine the sample count for each class in your training set. I will use your data above

```
class_weights={}
samples=[ 217, 317, 235, 489, 177, 377, 534, 180, 425,192, 403, 324]
max_sample=np.max(samples)
print (max_sample)
for i in range (len(samples)):
    class_weights[i]=max_sample/samples[i]
for key, value in class_weights.items():
    print ( key, ' : ', value)
```

result will be

```
534
0  :  2.4608294930875574
1  :  1.6845425867507886
2  :  2.272340425531915
3  :  1.0920245398773005
4  :  3.016949152542373
5  :  1.4164456233421752
6  :  1.0
7  :  2.966666666666667
8  :  1.2564705882352942
9  :  2.78125
10  :  1.3250620347394542
11  :  1.6481481481481481

​
```

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for Your kind cooperation. This is very kind of You. It means a lot.

Another question is mine, after getting this result what should I have to do? In where should I use this result?

Comment: Sir I call the class_weight function like this 

`History = Model.fit_generator(generator= train_data, steps_per_epoch= 3333//BATCH_SIZE , epochs= NO_OF_EPOCHS , validation_data= valid_data, validation_steps=1 ,callbacks = e_s, class_weight=class_weight)`

is it correct?